# Understanding Pack method in Perl

Tags: perl

I am not a Perl programmer but had some question about Pack method that I am looking at. I am seeing following code:

```
$diag_cmd = pack("CCSV", DIAG_SUBSYS_CMD_F, DIAG_SUBSYS_PWRDB, PWRDB_DIAG_PKT_SCRIPT | $processor_select, length($s_part)) . $s_part;
```

In my understanding Pack method takes some data values and pack it into a Byte. Now I have some questions about the piece of code above:

1. What does "CCSV" stand for?
2. The third argument is  PWRDB_DIAG_PKT_SCRIPT | $processor_select where PWRDB_DIAG_PKT_SCRIPT is 2 and $processor_select is 0. what would it pass to pack '2' or '0' and why?
3. I thought function call is over at $diag_cmd = pack("CCSV", DIAG_SUBSYS_CMD_F, DIAG_SUBSYS_PWRDB, PWRDB_DIAG_PKT_SCRIPT | $processor_select, length($s_part)) but there is some extra  `. $s_part`. what is that?
4. Last argument is length. What role does it play in pack method?

Comment: or http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html

Comment: That answers my first question very correctly. But still dont understand 2,3,4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html; essentially pack takes a format string (`CCSV` in your case) that tells it how to assemble the remainder of its arguments into a string.
2. `|` is the bitwise or operator; it ors two numbers (or two strings, but that doesn't appear to be what you are doing) one bit at a time.  So 2|9 is 0b0010|0b1001 is 0b1011 is 11.  2|0 would be just 2.
3. Just as you can say `$x = "a" . "b";` to assign `ab` to `$x`, here you are assigning the concatenation of the result of pack and another string variable.
4. The length expression is just one of the arguments; in particular the one that will be encoded by the V in the template.